# regexp_matches function does not give any result

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to extract,

> 002267b4-ad06-11e4-89ca-59f94b49bbc0

the above string from another string. What I have tried is,

```
select regexp_matches('class 1 type 1 cat 1 002267b4-ad06-11e4-89ca-59f94b49bbc0' , '\b\w{1,8}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,12}\b' )
```

This does not give any result, BUT when I check the regular expression from an online tool it selects the correct string I want. Must be an issue in the postgresql query.

Please help.

Comment: Put the pattern inside `()`

Comment: `\b` is a [shortcut for "backspace"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CHARACTER-ENTRY-ESCAPES-TABLE) - I don't think this is what you want. I also don't think you need to escape the `-` outside of a range operator (`[..]`). I think `'\w{1,8}-\w{1,4}-\w{1,4}-\w{1,4}-\w{1,12}'` should do it

Comment: Try `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` instead of first and last `\b`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS.

Comment: @hjpotter92 But posgres says no brackets http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_string_functions.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks it worked but Why? Coz regex worked fine when I checked in this site https://regex101.com/ Why only in postgres?

Comment: Ok, try `\m` for the first `\b` and `\M` for the last `\b`: `\m\w{1,8}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,12}\M`. `\b` means a backspace in postgresql regex flavor.

Comment: No idea, but according to [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) `\b` means backspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoding to [PostgreSQL regex documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS), you need to use `\m` for a beginning of a word, and `\M` for the end of the word boundaries. `\b` means a backspace. So, your regex should lool like:

```
select regexp_matches('class 1 type 1 cat 1 002267b4-ad06-11e4-89ca-59f94b49bbc0' , '\m\w{1,8}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,4}\-\w{1,12}\M' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(
  'class 1 type 1 cat 1 002267b4-ad06-11e4-89ca-59f94b49bbc0',
  '[^-]{1,8}-[^-]{1,4}-[^-]{1,4}-[^-]{1,4}-[^-]{1,12}'
);
```

This can be [Fiddel around with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7fb32/9)